# How to trigger mouseEntered event on rectangle form created, not on the panel itself?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, rectangles, bounds

I'm trying to have a popup window when I do a mouse over of a rectangle created in my code.

Basically I create a rectangle with my mouse. I get the correct dimension but the panel seems to be responding to the event and not the rectangle itself.

Here is the code:

```
int coordX = evt.getX();
int coordY = evt.getY();

List<Region> listeRegions; // revenir implanter region 

List<Pays> listePays = controleur.getListePays();
for (Pays i : listePays)
{
    double height = i.getForme().getBounds().getHeight();
    double width = i.getForme().getBounds().getWidth();
    double coordXRec = i.getForme().getBounds().getX();
    double coordYrec = i.getForme().getBounds().getY();
    
    if (coordX > coordXRec && coordX < coordXRec + width && coordY > coordYrec && coordY < coordYrec + height){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i.GetInfoPays());
    }
}
```

All of the variables works, including the event stocked from the mouse in `coordX` and `coordY`.

I'm using a pretty simple algorithm to check if my mouse has entered the rectangle but here's the thing. Nothing seems to be working. If I remove one of the condition for example let's remove `coordY > coordYrec + height`, then I'd be able get true on my if to get the info of the country if I enter the panel from the bottom side (while still maintaining the condition for `coordX`) but naturally it now fits the boundaries of the panel and not the rectangle.

I was wondering if it was a problem with my `mouseEntered` event that is 'priorizing' my panel and now the rectangle form I create.

So in that case I want the popup to happen when I entered my blue rectangle, not boundaries of the panel that surrounds it(white area):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6pfp.png]

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Is it possible that my evt.getX() and evt.getY() only return the coord the first time i enter the panel and stop there ?

Comment: *"Let me know if you need more information."* Well it's not specifically what I need. For me this is purely academic, but.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). **Other tips:** 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: BTW - perhaps(1) this code needs a `MouseMotionListener` rather than a `MouseListener`. 1) I say 'perhaps' because it's not clear what listener is being used *currently*. One of many reasons to post an MRE / SSCCE.

Comment: *"..perhaps this code needs a `MouseMotionListener`"* Yep, that works. The orange `+` marks the mouse position in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnBnG.png).

Comment: Events are only generated for components. I can't tell if you "blue rectangle" is a component or custom painting. *I'm using a pretty simple algorithm to check if my mouse has entered the rectangle* - use a `Shape` object. It supports a `contains(...)` method. A `Rectangle` can be used as a `Shape`.

Comment: Yes, a few of you wrote it. It was solved by using a MouseMovedEvent instead of an entered event. Thanks